# How to open a new UNSAVED contact in Outlook Mac with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I can create a new contact and open it for display in Mac Outlook 2011 using AppleScript:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newContact to make new contact with properties {first name:"Fred", last name:"Flintstone"}
    open newContact
end tell
```

But this contact is already saved. Is there a way I can open a new and *unsaved* Outlook contact, fill in the properties, and allow the user to decide whether or not to save it?

I've tinkered around with "make new window" but I can't get anywhere there. I consistently get the error:

```
error "Microsoft Outlook got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000
```

I think I need to go about this a different way, but nothing in the Outlook AppleScript dictionary looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by scripting the UI elements to open a new contact:

```
tell application "System Events"
  click menu item "Contact" of menu 1 of menu item "New" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Outlook"
end tell
```

Update:
But the caveat is that the new contact is not a AppleScriptable object until it is added to the Outlook database, i.e. it is saved.  If you add these lines to the above script, you can see this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
  set contactWindow to item 1 of (windows whose index is 1)
  get object of contactWindow
end tell
```

object of contactWindow is a missing value.

So if you want to use the Outlook Applescript dictionary APIs to edit the fields of a new contact, then that contact must have first been saved.

2nd Update:
The following, when placed in the 'tell application "System Events"' block after creating a contact will set the lastname, firstname and email address for that contact using UI element scripting:

```
set lastName to "Einstein"
set firstName to "Albert"
set emailAddress to "a.einstein@relativity.com"

set value of text field 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 of application process "Outlook" to lastName
set value of text field 2 of splitter group 1 of window 1 of application process "Outlook" to firstName
set value of text field 6 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process "Outlook" to emailAddress
```

As mentioned in the comments, "Enable access for assistive devices" needs to be enabled for this to work.  This can also be done programmatically from AppleScript:

```
-- turn on UI automation - may throw a permissions dialog
if UI elements enabled is false then
  set UI elements enabled to true
end if
```

Comment: Ah, that's great. But then can the fields (e.g. first name, last name) be filled in?

Comment: @Nicholas - please see the edit I just made to my answer.  I think what you need to do may not be possible without the contact first being saved.  Alternatively you can use UI Element scripting to edit the fields in an unsaved contact, but that is generally cumbersome.  Which fields did you want to edit?

Comment: I think you're right. I'll need to enter data into many of the fields. I'll tinker around to see if this is a viable solution for me (though I think we're very clear on the limits of both solutions).

Comment: For anyone trying this, I had to go to System Preferences > Accessibility and check "Enable access for assistive devices" to allow this to work.

Comment: You can also do this programmatically as follows:<br>
        -- turn on UI automation - may throw a permissions dialog <br>
        if UI elements enabled is false then <br>
            set UI elements enabled to true <br>
        end if <br>